# Nesting commandLink to outputFormat

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I was wondering if it is possible to nest a h:commandLink into a h:outputFormat message, e.g.:

messages.properties

```
disclaimerLink=Click {0] for Disclaimer
```

Now I would like to do something like this

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{msgs['disclaimerLink']}" >
    <f:param>
        <s:link view="/footer.xhtml" value=" #{msgs['disclaimer']}" target="_blank">
            <f:param name="t" value="disclaimer"/>
        </s:link> 
    </f:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

But it seems to me that `f:param` doesn't accept the "value" as a child. Am I right? Maybe I've got an other option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSFs: commandLink as a parameter for outputFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205386/jsfs-commandlink-as-a-parameter-for-outputformat)

Answer (score 1):

Split the message in two parts. `Click` and `for Disclaimer` and put a link between them.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is the fact that it is simply not acceptable from i18n stand point. This poses Localizability problem as translator is not aware that this is one sentence. And it is not so obvious how to re-order the sentence. In worse case scenario one would simply re-use "Click" making correct translation impossible...

Comment: make a different key for this click. `disclaimer.click` for example. Btw, check the link by McDowell