# How to pass rich params to jsf for i18n?

Tags: jsf, internationalization

I am using jsf to render my html pages and I am using the nifty resource bundle loading to add i18n to the various pages. The problem I am having is that with outputFormat you can not pass in any "rich" parameters. For instance this sentance:

This my favorite [search engine](http://google.com), you should check it out.

It would be nice to do something like this:

```
 <h:outputFormat value="#{bundle.favItemLineWithParam}>
      <f:param>
           <h:outputFormat value="#{bundle.searchEngine}>
                <f:param>
                     <h:link value="http://google.com">
                </f:param>
           </h:outputFormat>
      </f:param>
 </h:outputFormat>
```

but that is not allowed, it would seem like the only option is to render the links in java with a backing bean or something. Any Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSFs: commandLink as a parameter for outputFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205386/jsfs-commandlink-as-a-parameter-for-outputformat)

Comment: in case you miss it in that post, you can read about how to do this with a custom control [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/08/jsf-custom-format-panel-control-for.html).

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. You need to use plain HTML in the bundle value and set `escape="false"`.

```
favItem = This is my favourite <a href="{1}">{0}</a>, you should check it out.
```

with

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{bundle.favItem}" escape="false">
    <f:param value="search engine" />
    <f:param value="http://google.com" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

---

**Update**:

Since version 1.5, it's possible with [`<o:param>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/param) of JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org):

```
favItem = This is my favourite {0}, you should check it out.
searchEngine = search engine
```

with

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{bundle.favItem}" escape="false">
    <o:param><a href="http://google.com">#{bundle.searchEngine}</a></o:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

Comment: Hmm... Thats wat I was afraid of. Unfortunately my urls are generated via h:link to work with prettyfaces.